# SoundCloud - How to login each user without redirecting to a page

Tags: oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I am creating an mobile app for soundcloud. its an hobby project to learn .

after reading documents I understood that to get a token (to get a user authenticated) we need to redirect to another page and from there user will login and wil get back a token …

In my app I don't want to redirect to connect page to authenticate user ...Is there any api to login from my app directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing supported is the User credentials flow:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/authentication#user-credentials-flow

This would allow you to prompt the user for their credentials, which you would then pass to the token endpoint when requesting an access token. The user won't be redirected to a browser window.

You can of course use the more common authorization flow with a mobile app, just provide a  uri scheme that your application can register itself as the handler of, e.g. my-sc-app://callback